# Why do all returned terminal commands output like this?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

[image]

This is running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit version of PhpStorm 2016.1.2

I can't figure out why all my commands output like this?

Even if I configure the terminal inside PhpStorms settings to use Git's bash.exe, it still outputs the same?

Comment: Those are Escape sequences (coloring info). Looks like your console/terminal does not support it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22401660/2908724

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments as it pointed me in the perfect direction to figure it out.

I had to open a new windows command, right click the top of the window, selected 'Defaults', and unchecked 'Use legacy mode'. Then relaunched the Terminal in PhpStorm.

[image]

**After**:

[image]